# Change Color Of button According to time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of button according to my shift timings. Likewise if it's a morning shift going the button color should be blue and in the evening it should automatically change to red or any different color. I need four different colors. Can anyone help me in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hex").on('change', function(){  
    var hex = $("#hex").val();
    $("#btn").css({"background-color":hex});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hex" />
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you mean the time of day on the client machine is in the evening? What four colours should be used? You've only said there's two times to change...? None of this makes sense.

Comment: i need a button in which color changes automatically according to system time... 1st color in morning shift 2nd color in evening shift 3rd color in night shift and 4th color in overnight shift so that the user can understand which shift is currently going on. and the four colors are .. Green  blue , red, yellow

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what times those shifts are?

Comment: there will be fix timings .. 9 am to 3pm , 3pm to 9pm , 9pm to 3 am and again 3 am to 9am

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code to help you. Just get the hours from the `Date()`, use the `if-else` condition or `switch-case` and add the colors that you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hours = new Date().getHours();
  var color = '#d00';
  if (hours < 12)
    color = '#FFF';
  else if (hours > 12 && hours < 15)
    color = '#000';
  $("#btn").css({
    "background-color": color
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hex" />
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just break the 24 hours in four set each of 6 hours. Change as per your need. Use script as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var hours = new Date().getHours();
 var color = '';
 if (hours <= 6)
   color = '#f00';
 else if (hours > 6 && hours <= 12)
   color = '#0f0';
 else if (hours > 12 && hours <= 18)
   color = '#00f';
 else if (hours > 18 && hours <= 24)
   color = '#ff0';
 $("#btn").css({"background-color": color});
});
```